# CodedUI TreeItem changing value property

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Each of the UIElement in the TreeItem has a 'Value' property in SearchProperties. This Value appears to have the depth , for instance My Computer has a Value of 1, Some folder within My Computer has Value 2 and so on. I am trying to modify my code to dynamically locate the folder names. In order to do this, I am trying to pass the name property and value property as search properties. However WinControl.PropertyNames.Value does not exist. I can do something like

con.SearchProperties.Add(WinControl.PropertyNames.Name, folderName[ii], PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains)).

UserInput could be like: C:\folder1\folder2\folder3 or C:\folder1\folder2

Depending on the number of folders in user input, the treeItem needs to be traversed. I am trying to do something like

```
string path = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3";
string[] folderNames = path.Split("\\");
string driveLetter = folderNames[0];
for (int index=1; index < folderNames.Length; index++)
{
UITestControl locateTreeItem = this.UIBrowseForFolderWindow.UITreeViewWindow.UIDesktopTreeItem.UIComputerTreeItem; //Points to My Computer
locateTreeItem.SearchProperties.Add(WinControl.PropertyNames.Name, folderName[index], PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

locateTreeItem.SearchProperties.Add(WinControl.PropertyNames.Value, index+1, PropertyExpressionOperator.Equals);

Mouse.Click(locateTreeItem);
}
```

However there seems to be no such option WinControl.PropertyNames.Value. I get compileTime error 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls.WinControl.PropertyNames' does not contain a definition for 'Value'. However this property shows up in Edit Search Properties window for a treeItem along with Name, ControlType etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at UITestControl.SearchProperties.Add you'll notice that it takes strings as parameter, so you can just simply type ...Add("Value", (index + 1).ToString())

That also goes for almost every SetValue and GetValue functions you come across. (Edit2: come to think of it, those are mostly of the type object not string, sorry)

Or if you take a look at the generated code for TreeItems in the UIMap.Designer.cs it looks something like UITestControl.SearchProperties["Value"] = "0". So you could also go with locateTreeItem.SearchProperties["Value"] = (index + 1).ToString()

Edit: You should also consider including the tree hierarchy when creating your test controls. Something like this:

```
string path = @"C:\Windows\Boot\PCAT\hu-HU";
string[] folderNames = path.Split('\\');
WinTreeItem ParentTreeItem = this.UIMap.UIComputerWindow.UITreeViewWindow.UITreeViewTree.UIDesktopTreeItem.UIComputerTreeItem;
int Depth = int.Parse(ParentTreeItem.SearchProperties["Value"]) + 1;

for (int index = 0; index < folderNames.Length; index++)
{
    WinTreeItem TreeItem = new WinTreeItem(ParentTreeItem);
    if (index == 0)
        TreeItem.SearchProperties["Name"] = string.Format("Local Disk ({0})", folderNames[0]);
    else                  
        TreeItem.SearchProperties["Name"] = folderNames[index];
    TreeItem.SearchProperties["Value"] = Depth.ToString();
    ++Depth;
    TreeItem.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.NextSibling);
    TreeItem.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.ExpandWhileSearching);
    ParentTreeItem = TreeItem;
}
Mouse.Click(ParentTreeItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave the Value property for the Parent and Child tree items in the get function as below and it worked:

```
//In the Get Function of the Parent Tree Item

int Depth = 3  //This is what it shows for Value property when I use the crosshair tool for Parent tree item

ParentTreeItem.SearchProperties["Value"] = Depth.ToString();

//In the Get Function of the Child Tree Item

int Depth = 4  //This is what it shows for Value property when I use the crosshair tool for Child tree item

ChildTreeItem.SearchProperties["Value"] = Depth.ToString();
```